# Why doesn't Poison Ivy cause a reaction under one's fingernails?

Tags: botany

Okay, so I pulled up a bunch of Poison Ivy last week and I got itchy up and down my arms. I scratch and I think that causes the oil to spread causing more misery. However I notice that I don't get a reaction under my nails where I would think the oil might accumulate. Why not? The skin under the nail seems relatively delicate and yet it doesn't react. ?